# How to notify when the tcp connection lost on the port 5228 between the phone and google servers

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I go through the link - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/fslYqYrULto/lU2D3Qe1mugJ

what i found ,

- while the tcp conection do not transmit packets for a certain time,  Mobile carriers or wifi routers, consider that connection as inactive and kill that tcp connection.
- Until the connection is re-established no gcm push notification is received.

In this scenario, is there any way to be notified when the tcp connection is lost. So that my app becomes aware that, in this period no push will be received and can try to handle the case.